# Can't resolve all parameters for component (?) with SystemJS

Tags: angular, systemjs

Some background information:
I'm trying to incorporate my angular application into this "metaframework", [single-spa](https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa).
I've done `ng eject` and am using webpack to output the bundle in 'amd' format. I'm then using SystemJS to import the bundle.

I think this setup might be the reason I'm getting this error because I didn't have this error when I ran the app normally.

I don't get this error when I use forwardRef in the constructor. I think this is because the service is not being defined when the component is called, which makes me think something with the imports/providers is not working.

`@Inject(forwardRef(() => TestService)) private testService: TestService`

This is the component getting the error:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private testService: TestService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { TestService } from './test.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [ TestService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

// ADD THE FOLLOWING -----------------------------------------

import singleSpaAngular2 from 'single-spa-angular2';
import './polyfills';
// import './styles';

const ngLifecycles = singleSpaAngular2({

  // A function that takes in no arguments and returns a DOMElement.
  // This dom element is where the angular application will be bootstrapped, mounted, and unmounted.
  domElementGetter: domElementGetter,

  // An Angular 2 module class. If you're using Typescript or ES6 decorators, this is a class with the @NgModule decorator on it.
  mainModule: AppModule,

  // The platform with which to bootstrap your module. The "Angular platform"
  // refers to whether the code is running on the browser, mobile, server, etc.
  // In the case of a single-spa application, you should use the platformBrowserDynamic platform.
  angularPlatform: platformBrowserDynamic(),

  // An html string that will be put into the DOM Element returned by domElementGetter.
  // This template can be anything, but it is recommended that you keeping it simple by making it only one Angular component.
  // For example, <my-component /> is recommended, but <div><my-component /><span>Hello</span><another-component /></div> is allowed.
  // Generally the root angular component (selector in app.component.ts and index.html)
  template: `<example-app />`,

  // Router: (optional) The angular router class. If not provided, single-spa-angular2 will assume you are not using @angular/router.
  // Router
});

export function bootstrap() {
  return ngLifecycles.bootstrap();
}

export function mount() {
  return ngLifecycles.mount();
}

export function unmount() {
  return ngLifecycles.unmount();
}

function domElementGetter() {
  // Make sure there is a div for us to render into
  let el = document.getElementById( 'example-child-app' );
  if (!el) {
    el = document.createElement( 'div' );
    el.id = 'example-child-app';
    document.body.appendChild( el );
  }

  return el;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)        // REMOVE THIS
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const customProperties = require('postcss-custom-properties');

const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, SourceMapDevToolPlugin, NamedModulesPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { NamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin, BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

// const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');                                // REMOVE THIS
// const realNodeModules = fs.realpathSync(nodeModules);                                        // REMOVE THIS
// const genDirNodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', '$$_gendir', 'node_modules');      // REMOVE THIS
// const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","vendor","main"];           // REMOVE THIS
const minimizeCss = false;
const baseHref = "";
const deployUrl = "";
const postcssPlugins = function () {
        // safe settings based on: https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/358#issuecomment-283696193
        const importantCommentRe = /@preserve|@licen[cs]e|[@#]\s*source(?:Mapping)?URL|^!/i;
        const minimizeOptions = {
            autoprefixer: false,
            safe: true,
            mergeLonghand: false,
            discardComments: { remove: (comment) => !importantCommentRe.test(comment) }
        };
        return [
            postcssUrl([
                {
                    // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
                    filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('/') && !url.startsWith('//'),
                    url: ({ url }) => {
                        if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//) || deployUrl.startsWith('/')) {
                            // If deployUrl is absolute or root relative, ignore baseHref & use deployUrl as is.
                            return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${url}`;
                        }
                        else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                            // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                            return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                                `/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                        }
                        else {
                            // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                            // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                            return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    // TODO: inline .cur if not supporting IE (use browserslist to check)
                    filter: (asset) => !asset.hash && !asset.absolutePath.endsWith('.cur'),
                    url: 'inline',
                    // NOTE: maxSize is in KB
                    maxSize: 10
                }
            ]),
            autoprefixer(),
            customProperties({ preserve: true })
        ].concat(minimizeCss ? [cssnano(minimizeOptions)] : []);
    };




module.exports = {
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules",
      // "./node_modules"          // REMOVE THIS
    ],
    "symlinks": true,
    "alias": rxPaths(),
    "mainFields": [
      "browser",
      "module",
      "main"
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules",
      // "./node_modules"          // REMOVE THIS
    ],
    "alias": rxPaths()
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src/main.ts"
    ],
    // "polyfills": [               // REMOVE THIS
    //   "./src/polyfills.ts"
    // ],
    // "styles": [                  // REMOVE THIS
    //   "./src/styles.css"
    // ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js",
    "crossOriginLoading": false,
    "libraryTarget": "amd"           // ADD THIS
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader",
        "options": {
          "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
          "limit": 10000
        }
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader",
        "options": {
          "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
          "limit": 10000
        }
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "precision": 8,
              "includePaths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "paths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "precision": 8,
              "includePaths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "paths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.ts$/,
        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        "context": "src",
        "to": "",
        "from": {
          "glob": "assets/**/*",
          "dot": true
        }
      },
      {
        "context": "src",
        "to": "",
        "from": {
          "glob": "favicon.ico",
          "dot": true
        }
      }
    ], {
      "ignore": [
        ".gitkeep",
        "**/.DS_Store",
        "**/Thumbs.db"
      ],
      "debug": "warning"
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      "exclude": /(\\|\/)node_modules(\\|\/)/,
      "failOnError": false,
      "onDetected": false,
      "cwd": "/Users/rmadan/a1/example-child-app"
    }),
    new NamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin(),
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({                    // REMOVE THIS
    //   "template": "./src/index.html",
    //   "filename": "./index.html",
    //   "hash": false,
    //   "inject": true,
    //   "compile": true,
    //   "favicon": false,
    //   "minify": false,
    //   "cache": true,
    //   "showErrors": true,
    //   "chunks": "all",
    //   "excludeChunks": [],
    //   "title": "Webpack App",
    //   "xhtml": true,
    //   "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
    //     let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
    //     let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
    //     if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
    //         return 1;
    //     }
    //     else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
    //         return -1;
    //     }
    //     else {
    //         return 0;
    //     }
    // }
    // }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    // new CommonsChunkPlugin({                    // REMOVE THIS
    //   "name": [
    //     "inline"
    //   ],
    //   "minChunks": null
    // }),
    // new CommonsChunkPlugin({                    // REMOVE THIS
    //   "name": [
    //     "vendor"
    //   ],
    //   "minChunks": (module) => {
    //             return module.resource
    //                 && (module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules)
    //                     || module.resource.startsWith(genDirNodeModules)
    //                     || module.resource.startsWith(realNodeModules));
    //         },
    //   "chunks": [
    //     "main"
    //   ]
    // }),
    new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      "filename": "[file].map[query]",
      "moduleFilenameTemplate": "[resource-path]",
      "fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate": "[resource-path]?[hash]",
      "sourceRoot": "webpack:///"
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": [
        "main"
      ],
      "minChunks": 2,
      "async": "common"
    }),
    new NamedModulesPlugin({}),
    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      "entryModule": __dirname + '/src/app/app.module#AppModule',       // ADD THIS
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "platform": 0,
      "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments/environment.ts": "environments/environment.ts"
      },
      "sourceMap": true,
      "tsConfigPath": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "skipCodeGeneration": true,
      "compilerOptions": {}
    })
  ],
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  },
  "devServer": {
    "historyApiFallback": true
  }
};
```

Let me know if I you want to see any other files.

Comment: which component you are getting  the error??

Comment: I'm getting the error in TestComponent